# Auto detect USB and copy sam file to usb

Tags: batch-file, usb-drive

```
wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=2 get deviceid>usb.txt
```

Now how to use that deviceid `D:` so that we change directory and copy sam file to it?

…Or is there another easy way to do it!?

Comment: Type `wmic logicaldisk get /?` and `wmic logicaldisk get /format:list`.

Comment: Just be aware that a drivetype of `2` does not determine USB drives, it selects those drives which have registered as removable. All USB drives do not do that and some fixed drives also register themselves as removable too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you try something like this, it is not guaranteed to only find portable USB devices, but is closer that accepting `DriveType=2`:

```
@Echo Off
For /F Delims^=^= %%A In ('Set _ 2^>Nul')Do Set "%%A="
For /F Delims^= %%A In ('WMIC DiskDrive Where "InterfaceType='USB'" Assoc^
 /AssocClass:Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition 2^>Nul^|Find /I "_DiskPartition."'
)Do For /F Tokens^=2Delims^=^" %%B In ("%%A"
)Do For /F Tokens^=4Delims^=^" %%C In ('WMIC Path Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition^
 ^|FindStr/C:"%%B" 2^>Nul')Do (For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%D In ('WMIC^
 LogicalDisk Where "DeviceID='%%C'" Get DeviceID^,VolumeName')Do Echo( %%D
    Call Set "_C=%%_C%%%%C")
If Not Defined _C Echo( You don't have a USB drive connected&&GoTo :EndIt
If "%_C:~,2%"=="%_C%" GoTo Picked
Echo( Enter the USB drive letter from the above [%_C::=%]:
For /F "Tokens=2Delims=?" %%A In ('Choice/C %_C::=%')Do Set "_L=%%A:"
:Picked
If Not Defined _L (Call:Tasks %_C%)Else Call:Tasks %_L%
:EndIt
>Nul Timeout 5
Exit/B
:Tasks
Copy /Y "FileName.sam" %1:\ >Nul 2>&1
```

This has the added 'feature' that if there is more than one detected drive, you will be offered the opportunity to choose between them for the destination.

*I have created this in such a way as you do not need to touch anything in this script except for the task(s) under the bottom label, where `%1` is your detected drive letter. In this case you're likely to want to change the doublequoted string on the last line.*

Comment: That's an huge program... Okay let me get it how it's working... I knock you if I get any issue.... AND thanks for the suggestion 

Comment: Doing a quick estimated count up, I'm going to suggest that this script will come in at less that a thousand bytes, you may call it huge, but I think not. If you haven't got enough space on your drives for it, you really need more than just scripting help. _BTW, providing answers here does not tie me into a tech support role. Unlike many of those who provide answers around here, I am not particularly interested in explaining how my scripts work, providing question and answer sessions on them, or making unnecessary modifications to them._

Comment: @user11196744, feedback on the solution would help the site and future readers. After almost one day, I'd have expected something a little more; acceptance, upvote, or at the very least whether it worked for you.

Comment: As you see um new in this... I don't know how the things work... So guide me I'll do that for you 